# Superbadge: Lightning component framework- Challenge 2

Tags: lightning

I am stuck in challenge 2. Functionality is working as expected. But I get error as - ***Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong: 
The BoatSearch component should instantiate the BoatSearchForm and BoatSearchResults components.***
Below is my BoatSearch component.

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <lightning:card title="Find a Boat"  class="slds-m-top_10px">
        <c.BoatSearchForm/>
    </lightning:card>
    <lightning:card title="Matching Boats">
        <c.BoatSearchResults/>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

Any tips/links to documentation is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Don't you mean `<c:BoatSearchForm />` and `<c:BoatSearchResults />`?

Comment: That's correct. My bad. It's working as expected.